# how can I convert a list to a dataframe

Tags: r, list

I have this list of 16 items:

```
[[1]]
[1] -3.3354997  0.2301914  1.0979842

[[2]]
[1] -3.3275922  0.2505644  0.8881143

[[3]]
[1] -3.3743078  0.3318792  0.4635529

[[4]]
[1] -3.4310944  0.3303742  0.4707966

[[5]]
[1] -3.5093978  0.3527943  0.3970423
...
```

I would like to have such a dataframe where mu, szig, and kszi are columns. For each row I want to calculate a new value `1-exp(-(1+kszi*((0-mu)/szig))^(-1/kszi))` and add that to the dataframe as a 4th column.

Comment: You may want to check out `help("as.data.frame")`

Answer (score 0):

If you intended the elements of your list to be the columns of your dataframe, you could use `as.data.frame(l)` by itself (where `l` is whatever the name of your list is). Since you want the elements of your list to be the rows of your dataframe, we also have to enlist the help of `do.call("rbind", l)`:

```
# Since you decided not to helpfully provide your data in an easily usable
# form, such as via the output of dput(), I recreate some of it here:
l <- list(c(-3.3354997,  0.2301914,  1.0979842),
          c(-3.3275922,  0.2505644,  0.8881143))
# We can use as.data.frame() on the output of do.call("rbind", l) to make
# the dataframe you're looking for:
(l_df <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", l)))
#          V1        V2        V3
# 1 -3.335500 0.2301914 1.0979842
# 2 -3.327592 0.2505644 0.8881143
# Here's the column name you wanted:
names(l_df) <- c("mu", "szig", "kszi")
# We can then add your new column normally:
l_df$new_column <- 1-exp(-(1+l_df$kszi*((0-l_df$mu)/l_df$szig))^(-1/l_df$kszi))
# And let's take a look at the result:
l_df
#          mu      szig      kszi new_column
# 1 -3.335500 0.2301914 1.0979842 0.07328838
# 2 -3.327592 0.2505644 0.8881143 0.05511381
```

As I mention in the comments to the code above, for future reference it is much more helpful to potential answerers if you post your example data using the output of the `dput()` command. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @duckmayr:

```
# libraries ------------------------------------------------------------------------

library(dplyr)                    # you don't really need it but %>% looks great
library(purrr)                    # i use it to create example dataset only

# example data ---------------------------------------------------------------------

l <- replicate(16,                                        
               map_dbl(c(-3, 0, 1), ~ rnorm(1, mean = .x)), 
               simplify = F
               )

# explore the data -----------------------------------------------------------------

glimpse(l)                         

List of 16
 $ : num [1:3] -1.589 0.434 2.359
 $ : num [1:3] -3.962 0.347 2.985
 $ : num [1:3] -3.765 -0.115 0.117
 .................................
 $ : num [1:3] -2.125 -0.116 1.363

# convert list 2 data.frame, do some math ------------------------------------------

dat <- setNames(                      # set names for columns of returned data.frame
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, l),       # use rbind.data.frame to return data.frame
  c('mu', 'szig', 'kszi')             # vector of column names
  ) %>%                               # pipe resulting data.frame into mutate do math
  mutate(newcol = 1 - exp(-(1 + kszi * (-mu / szig))^(-1 / kszi)))

# examine the results --------------------------------------------------------------

head(dat)

         mu       szig      kszi    newcol
1 -1.589332  0.4341922 2.3591750 0.3180414
2 -3.962315  0.3472064 2.9853146 0.2619436
3 -3.764680 -0.1152990 0.1165112       NaN
4 -3.068161  0.9600714 1.6944156 0.2838741
5 -2.305584 -0.5308407 2.9096659       NaN
6 -2.671408  3.3653275 0.9817123 0.4265145

# post your answer to stackoverflow -------------------------------------------------

[1] "in progress..."
```